# Trouble with while-loop statement

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I keep getting errors when I try to compile these codes below, I'm currently using JCreator.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Number //class name here, same as file name

 {
 public Number()throws IOException{//constructor, place class name here
 // use BufferedReader class to input from the keyboard
 // declare a variable of type BufferedReader
 BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 //declare variable for input
 String inputString;

int number;
int counter;
int square;
int cube;
String goodMessage = "Thank you";
String badMessage = "Sorry";

//begin houseKeeping()
System.out.print("Please input number: ");
inputString = input.readLine();
number = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

//begin squareCube()
counter = 0;
while ((counter = 0)&&(number > 0)) {
    square = number*number;
    cube = number*number*number;
    System.out.print(square);
    System.out.print(cube);
}
if (counter = counter + 1);
if (counter < 3);
System.out.print("Enter input number: ");

//begin finishUp()
if (number > 0)
    System.out.println(goodMessage);

    else 
    System.out.println(badMessage);

 }//end constructor

 public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException // main method

 {
 new Number(); //class constructor name
 } // end the main method
 } // end the program
```

Error:

```
--------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
D:\INFO\INFO 1391\Number.java:27: error: bad operand types for binary operator '&&'
    while ((counter = 0)&&(number > 0)) {
                        ^
  first type:  int
  second type: boolean
1 error

Process completed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
counter = 0
```

should be

```
counter == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `=` operator to compare values; that's the assignment operator.  Use `==` to compare your `int` values:

```
while ((counter == 0)&&(number > 0)) {
```

The assignment operator here evaluates to an `int`, yielding the error message that you received.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced with == and I was able to run the codes, however when I entered numbers, it kept looping and never stops :(

Comment: Inside your while loop, you never change `number` or `counter` so there is no way for it to exit out of the while loop.

Comment: Thank you for the respond, Is there anyway I can get it to print out "goodMessage"?

Answer (score 0):

`while ((counter = 0)&&(number > 0))` is never true, because `(counter = 0)` assigns counter to be `0` and the value of that statement is the value of `counter`: `0`. And `0` is `int` and can't be converted to `boolean`.

Comment: `(counter = 0 &&...)` isn't false.  It wouldn't even compile, cause Java doesn't implicitly convert to boolean.

Comment: you are right... i was in c-land in my thoughts... i change my answer

Answer (score 0):

Where is the question?

There are so many errors in this code... 
To check if two integers are equal you have to write == not =. (In while and in if).

Comment: Note also, even once the conditions are fixed so that they compile, half are useless.  `if (counter < 3);` does nothing unless counter < 3, at which point it does...still nothing.  The semicolon at the end constitutes an empty statement; it's like saying `if (counter < 3) { }`.